# How to call method inside laravel View?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have controller which will load the view part

```
public function homePage(){
    $categories = Category::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('cart.index',compact('categories','products'));
}
```

Here is the View (basically checking for subcategory if there it will show otherwise skip)

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-bordered list-group-noicon uppercase">
    <li class="list-group-item active">
        @foreach($categories as $row)
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{$row->name}}</a>
            @if({{StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id)}})
                @foreach($subcategories as $sub)
                    <ul>                                        
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="size-11 text-muted pull-right">(123)</span> {{$sub->s_name}}</a></li>          
                    </ul>
                @endforeach 
            @else
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><span class="size-11 text-muted pull-right">(189)</span> {{$row->name}}</a></li>
            @endif
        @endforeach

    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the `checkSubcategory` method

```
public function checkSubcategory($id){
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $id = $category->id;
    $subcategories = DB::table ('subcategories')
        ->join('categories_subcategories','subcategories.id','=','categories_subcategories.subcategory_id')
        ->join('categories','categories_subcategories.category_id','=','categories.id')
        ->where('categories.id','=',$id)
        ->select('subcategories.name as s_name ')
        ->get(); 

    return $subcategories;
}
```

But i got syntax Error in line of calling method in View?
what could be the error ..is there any mistake calling method in view part?

Comment: `StapsController::checkSubcategory($id)` is not a static function so you can't call it like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic of `checkSubcategory` works fine in the controller itself, you have to transport it to the model. i.e make it model's method so from the view you could able to do something like the following:

```
....
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{$row->name}}</a>
                                        @if({{$row->checkSubcategory($row->id);}})
                                        <ul>
....
```

In other words, define this method in your `Category` model.

Comment: Ah, 57 seconds earlier.

Comment: How to called `$row->checkSubcategory()`  function?

Comment: @HIteshTank Define it in the model to act as a class's method.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error..though I put it inside of model..calling the method the way you have instructed

Comment: @User57 Also you have to notice that line in your code: `@if({{StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id);}})` remove the `;` at `..id);}}`

Comment: when i dd() the output I see it but the problem is how do print that return array from method  in blade?

Comment: @User57 Another notice, it is conditional statement so you should not use `{{}}` it should be  `@if(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id))`

Answer (score 0):

Place your function some other place, rather than controller. In your case, inside `Category` model, perhaps?

Then, in View you'll able to use your function like this:

```
$row->checkSubcategory($row->id)
```

No need to make function static.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relationship like this and call through object.

```
public function checkSubcategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\subcategories');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be one way to do that easily-

1. Custom Helper Function

**Custom Helper Function** 
Personally I prefer you to use custom helper function because you can call this function anywhere in your project.

- Within your **app/Http** directory, create a **helpers.php** file and add
  your functions.
- Within **composer.json**, in the autoload block, add `"files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"]`.
- Run composer **dump-autoload**.

Now, whatever you write in your **helpers.php** file, you can easily access.

** Note: Remember that, in **helpers.php** file, all the codes need to be function based. Don't use class in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to call your methods inside a view. In that case, either create a helper file and load the file using composer, or  you can use query scope. Give it a try. Using query scope

First add this in your category model.

```
function scopeCheckSubcategory(){
      DB::raw('(SELECT subcategories.name as s_name
       FROM `subcategories`
       INNER JOIN categories_subcategories on categories_subcategories.subcategory_id = subcategories.id 
       AND categories_subcategories.category_id = categories.id') AS s_name'
      )
}
```

Now call the scope

```
$categories = Category::CheckSubcategory->get();
```

Now check in your blade file

```
@if($row->s_name)
...
...
@endif
```

Comment: where to call the scope?

Comment: with your query. this way Category::CheckSubcategory->get(); Please read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your blade, here is corrected version,

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-bordered list-group-noicon uppercase">
    <li class="list-group-item active">
        @foreach($categories as $row)
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{$row->name}}</a>
            <ul>
                @if(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id)) 
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="size-11 text-muted pull-right">(123)</span> {{$sub->s_name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="size-11 text-muted pull-right">(189)</span> {{$row->name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        @endforeach 
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. `@if({{StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id);}})` this line is wrong(*syntax error*)
2. You have written two `endforeach` statements
3. Your `if statement` was closing after `endforeach` statement
4. You have `missing ul` tag in in `else statement`

Check above I hope this helps.

Comment: then how will you use `{{$sub->s_name}}`

Comment: Are you missing one more foreach loop ?                 @if(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id)) 
I think this line is @foreach(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id))  and $sub is instance of this foreach loop, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Mate, your code have only one foreach loop, can you edit question and correct the position of that foreach loop which is missing

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to add the line, But how can i print the data after i calling the method?

Comment: change your @if(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id))  to @foreach(StapsController::checkSubcategory($row->id) as $sub) and check

Comment: and please close foreach properly, remove else part, if it doesn't means anything or close it properly,